# Close a Custom Dialog from another class

Tags: android, dialog

I have 3 classes, one in my CustomDialog class, another one is a non-activity class where i call my custom dialog, and a third class that is my App class from where I want want to dismiss the custom dialog.

Custom Dialog class:

```
public class DCCView extends Dialog {



private final String dCancel= "CANCEL";
private ResultListener listener;
private Button btnCurrency1;
private Button btnCurrency2;
private Button btnCancel;
private TextView tvCurrency1;
private TextView tvCurrency2;
private TextView tvMsg;
private Handler mTimer;
private Response response;


public DCCView(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.dcc_interface);
    setCancelable(false);
    btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);

    tv1 = findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv2 = findViewById(R.id.tv2);
    tvMsg = findViewById(R.id.tv_dcc_msg);

    btnCurrency1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        response = Response.C1;
        cancelAlert();
        listener.onResult(response);
    });

    btnCurrency2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        response = Response.C2;
        cancelAlert();
        listener.onResult(response);
    });

    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        response = Response.CANCEL;
        cancelAlert();
        listener.onResult(response);
    });
}

public interface ResultListener {
    void onResult(Response response);
}

public void showDCC(String transCurrency, double transAmount, String dccCurrency, String dccAmount,String dataDisplay, @NonNull ResultListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
    Handler hnd = new Handler(getContext().getMainLooper());
    hnd.post(() -> {
        showAlert();
        btn1.setText(transCurrency);
        tv1.setText(String.format("%.2f",transAmount));
        btn2.setText(dccCurrency);
        tv2.setText(dccAmount);
        btnCancel.setText(dCancel);
        tvMsg.setText(dataDisplay);
    });
}

public void showAlert() {
    if (!isShowing()) {
        show();
    }
}

public void cancelAlert() {
    dismiss();
}
```

Non-activity class:

```
public class MSG1002{
    private static DCCView mDccView;

   public MSG1002() {
                Handler hnd = new Handler(App.getContext().getMainLooper());
    hnd.post(() -> {
        mDccView = new DCCView(App.getContext());
    });
   }

   public void process(){
   mDccView.showDCC(transactionCurrency, transA, dccCurrency, dccAmount, dataUserDisplay, (DCCView.Response response) -> {
                onDccResponse(response, socketCliente);
            });
   }
```

App class:

```
public class App extends Application{
private static DCCView mDCCView;
public static void realCancelAlert() {
    mDCCView.cancelAlert();
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mDCCView =new DCCView(mContext);
}
App.realCancelAlert();
```

So when I call my custom dialog from MSG1002 class, the dialog appears and it works, but when i what to close it from the class App with the command line App.realCancelAlert(); it doesn't close, and I don't understand why, because when I debug it the flow continues until it get's to dismiss() and it executs it but it doesn't dissapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING** *Fragment or activity that had shown a dialogue is responsible for closing it. No other class should be responsible for that. Otherwise, you are going down the route of memory leaks and code that is hard to maintain.*

#### Why doesn't it close?

Inside of your `App` class in `onCreate` you instantiate an object of type `DCCView` and store it as a static variable of that class. Let us say that variable is now pointing to the memory address 0x1234.

Then somewhere else in the code you invoke constructor of `MSG1002` class. It creates it's own instance of `DCCView` as `new DCCView(App.getContext());` and stores it inside of `MSG1002` class static variable. Let us say that variable is now pointing to the memory address 0x5678.

These variables `MSG1002.mDCCView` and `App.mDCCView` are two absolutely different variables that hold references to two different instances of `mDCCView`. That is why they have different addresses 0x1234 and 0x5678. By attempting to close `App.mDCCView` you do not close `MSG1002.mDCCView` dialogue.

#### How to fix?

*Note: strongly recommend to go away from holding a static reference to something related to UI as it holds the reference to `Context` value and prevents it from being garbage collected when it should be. That is memory leak.*

1. Make `private static DCCView mDCCView;` public or create get/set methods;

```
public class App extends Application{
    public static DCCView mDCCView;
    ...
```

2. Remove `private static DCCView mDccView;` from `MSG1002` class;
3. Update `MSG1002` class to use `App.mDccView`:

```
public class MSG1002{

   public MSG1002() {
       Handler hnd = new Handler(App.getContext().getMainLooper());
       hnd.post(() -> {
           App.realCancelAlert();
           App.mDccView = new DCCView(App.getContext());
       });
   }

   public void process(){
       App.mDccView.showDCC(transactionCurrency, transA, dccCurrency, dccAmount, dataUserDisplay, (DCCView.Response response) -> {
                onDccResponse(response, socketCliente);
            });
   }
   ...
}
```

*More about memory leaks: [memory leak in android](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4690472-memory-leaks-in-android), [stack overflow issues on dialogues causing memory leaks (9270 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20memory%20leak%20dialog%20site:stackoverflow.com%20&sxsrf=ALeKk02q5baqCPLC3i3KLjqQGzv43pHQXg:1594886711229&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpuoT_p9HqAhXG_KQKHRWrDT8QrAN6BAgBEAo&biw=1680&bih=938).*

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. You're right I shouldn't use static reference from the App, I will try to implement it different.